# Consistent off by one errors in go io.copy function for large content

Tags: go, error-handling, io

This one works consistently.

```
    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        ErrLog.Fatal(err)
    }
```

This one gives pretty consistent off by one errors (the last byte of the downloaded content is left off, in my case a closing `]` in a json response) for large-ish responses (MBs).

```
    if _, err := io.Copy(out, resp.Body); err != nil {
        ErrLog.Fatal(err)
    }
```

From [the examples on the official golang blog](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go), it looks like this *should* be valid syntax.

### Edit: Some more details and context

This is the error I get with the 2nd version of the code (more compact error handling)

```
ERROR: 2015/08/05 08:09:31 pull.go:257: unexpected end of JSON input
```

From this code in another function

```
err = json.Unmarshal(dat, &all_data)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

I found the off by one issue by looking at the first 10 and last 10 characters of the file in each case.  Here are the before and afters:

```
# Before (with error)
START:  [{"tags":[              END:    ersion":1}
START:  [{"_create              END:    "tags":[]}

# After
START:  [{"tags":[              END:    rsion":1}]
START:  [{"_create              END:    tags":[]}]
```

The files are 15-20 Mb json strings.

Comment: Can you add examples of a response Body that triggers this, and the error message you get?

Comment: @BravadaZadada I don't think so, but I could be missing something. `err` is reused again in code that follows, but by that time the data is already on disk (copy has finished) and the files are missing characters. Also, in both cases `io.Copy` works without returning an error.

Comment: @ash I added more details - pls let me know if anything else would be helpful!

Comment: Yeah that doesn't make much sense.  I think you'll have to provide the entire server handler.

Comment: Most likely your problem has nothing to do with "combined if vs if on extra line". Maybe it is a race condition which is triggered by the subtle timing difference between the two code snippets? Make sure everything else in your code is okay, especially non-racy: Racy programs have no defined behavior.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  It does look like a race condition now. The small timing difference that @Volker mentioned was enough to trigger the problem reliably before, but now that I changed some other stuff I'm seeing both good and bad responses with both versions of the code.  I'll add an answer with a more thorough response once I'm able to track down the bug.

Comment: To help you identify the source of your race you can use [Go's race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector) by adding `-race` to your go test/build/install command line. To help the race detector you should amke sure to run with [`GOMAXPROCS`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) > 1 and if using `go test` you should have some concurrent tests.

Comment: Thanks @DaveC - I gave the race detector a try but nothing was detected in either version of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was at least partially the result of a race condition.

I was not calling `.Close()` on the file `out` before exiting the function.  After adding that I have not been any more issues.

Why exactly this was causing **just the last byte** of the file to get dropped sometimes is a mystery to me.

Comment: @BravadaZadada If I had an idea of where the problem in the code may be coming from, I would.  But I didn't want to just paste a few hundred lines of messy go code.